# Java WebSocket API: Restrict service to certain domains

Tags: java, websocket, jsr356

As mentioned e.g. in the [HTML5Rocks WebSockets tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/#toc-cross),

> The server decides whether to make its service available to all clients or only those that reside on a set of well defined domains.

Ok, how to do that with the [Java API for WebSocket 1.0 (JSR 356)](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/websocket-1_0-fr-eval-spec/index.html) (running on [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator#checkOrigin`](https://tyrus.java.net/apidocs/1.4/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.html#checkOrigin%28java.lang.String%29)

Once registered, checkOrigin method will be called with "Origin" http header value as a parameter and then you can return true if its ok, or false, which should result in HTTP 403 - Origin not verified.

(please ignore any references to project Tyrus in javadoc, API (javax.websocket.*) is the same for all implementations).

Comment: Ok thanks - that should work. There is something however, that bothers me: `ServerEndpoint.configurator()` is documented as "If no configurator class is provided, the implementation uses its own." So e.g. Tomcat uses `org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.DefaultServerEndpointConfigurator`. If I don't want to lose the default logic for the other methods of Configurator, I'll have to subclass Tomcat's DefaultServerEndpointConfigurator - but then I won't be able to deploy it on other containers anymore... But ok, it seems to be the only possibility for now. Thanks again.

Comment: thats not true - just call super, it will work; default configurator will be found by the API class itself, so you can still stay container independent.

Comment: I mean .. its a class, you don't need to override methods you don't want to modify. Default implementation looks for container default implementation, you don't need to do anything about that.

Comment: When declaring my class, I need to write `extends org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.DefaultServerEndpointConfigurator`, if I want to use its methods via `super()` - therefore it _is_ container dependent.

Comment: you can write `public class MyServerConfigurator extends javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator { ... } `

Comment: this should help to understand how it works: https://java.net/projects/websocket-spec/sources/source-code-repository/content/tags/javax.websocket-all-1.0-final/api/server/src/main/java/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.java?rev=351

Comment: Ah, it becomes clear by looking into the source code of `javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator`. It wraps the Container's default configurator, and passes every method through. I wasn't aware of that just from reading the docs. Thanks.